# Fillable PDF using Adobe Acrobat 6.0 pro

Tags: javascript, date, pdf

I have Adobe acrobat pro 6.

I have pdf file having check boxes.

I want only one to be checkable, if we will check on other it will auto uncheck other.

and  field with dates in them - i.e. Date of Birth (mm/dd/yyyy) - should have proper date entry logic in place. For example, it should be [MM]/[DD]/[YYYY] textboxes with length restictions and validation

for date format check this
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96944763/IMM1295E.pdf

Phone number field should be validated (xxx) xxx-xxxx format, digits only - so make it separate entry fields then

please help m and let me know how can i make.

is it possibe without javascript?

if not please guide me with javascript

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, Acrobat 6 is really old, and should be replaced as quick as possible.

With the checkboxes, give them the same field name, but a different return value. This will cause the desired effect, and still allow to legally uncheck all options. If you are (re)creating the form, and you do not want to allow the user to uncheck all items after having checked one, use Radio Buttons instead.

For the date format, open the field properties dialog in Acrobat go to the Format tab and select "Date" as format; you will be able to specify the format.

The same applies to the phone numbers; however, I am not sure if that format has already been built in in Acrobat 6.